# sort a linked list in c(insertion between two node)?

Tags: c

this function works only if the first element is not the biggest

output:

```
a 55 n m

b 100 j k

c 88 i o
```

is there a way to solve this to obtain as output something like this
output:

```
a 55 n m

c 88 i o

b 100 j k
```

i think that the problem is at the end of the while cycle after the head insert.

```
LINK f1(){

    LINK p,head,tail;
    head=NULL;
    tail=NULL;
    char x[2];
    printf("Vuoi inserire un nuovo elemento?: ");
    scanf("%s",x);
    if(strcmp(x,"si")==0){
        p=newnode();
        printf("inserire: ");
        scanf("%s",p->d.t);
        printf("inserire: ");
        scanf("%d",&p->d.c);
        printf("inserire: ");
        scanf("%s",p->d.pr);
        printf("inserire: ");
        scanf("%s",p->d.m);
        p->next=NULL;
        if(head==NULL){head=p; tail=p;}
        else{tail->next=p; tail=p;}
        printf("Vuoi inserire un nuovo elemento?: ");
        scanf("%s",x);
    }
    while(strcmp(x,"si")==0){
        p=newnode();
        printf("inserire: ");
        scanf("%s",p->d.t);
        printf("inserire: ");
        scanf("%d",&p->d.c);
        printf("inserire: ");
        scanf("%s",p->d.pr);
        printf("inserire: ");
        scanf("%s",p->d.m);
        if(p->d.c<head->d.c){
            p->next=head; head=p;
        }
        else{
            tail->next=p; tail=p;
        }
    printf("Vuoi inserire un nuovo elemento?: ");
    scanf("%s",x);
    }
    return(head);
}
```

Comment: `strcmp(x,"si")==0` is a paradox.

Comment: Please learn to debug and turn all warnings to max while compiling. Then note that strings are null terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough space to store `"si"` in `char x[2];`

Switch to

```
char x[3];
```

One more for the trailing NUL character (`'\0'`)

And notice that `scanf` without a length specifier doesn't protect you from buffer overflows, consider using:

```
scanf("%2s",x);
```